# .Net Core - Send image through api = Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, mime

In the wwwroot folder of my .Net Core MVC application, I have some images. I need to serve these pictures to TopDesk, where I can put in a url which gets embedded. I have no influence on Topdesk. I can only change the way the image is served.

When I use a direct link to the image, it works. The image gets embedded

Example of direct url:

```
https://my.web.site/images/image001.jpeg
```

But there is a limited embedded size (600px) so i need to resize the images. For that purpose I wrote a very simple api controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Images/GetImage/{id}")]
public IActionResult GetImage(string id)
{
    try
    {
      var pad = $"c:\\Images\\{id}";
      if(System.IO.File.Exists(path))
      {
          var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
          var smallImage = ..... doing resizing;
          new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(Path.GetFileName(path), out var contentType);
          return File(smallImage , contentType ?? "application/octet-stream", $"{id}");
      }
      return NotFound();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

but the url

```
https://my.web.site/api/images/GetImage/image001.jpeg
```

results in

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
> image/jpeg

The image doesn't show.
When i test the url in Postman, it returns the image without warning.
What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning a `File`, try using `FileContentResult` instead:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Images/GetImage/{id}")]
public IActionResult GetImage(string id)
{
  try
  {
    var path = $"c:\\Images\\{id}";
    if(System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
      var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
      var smallImage = ..... doing resizing;
      new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(Path.GetFileName(path), out var contentType);
      return new FileContentResult(fileBytes, contentType ?? "application/octet-stream");
    }
  return NotFound();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    return BadRequest(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

When navigating to `/GetImage/{id}` with a browser, you will see that with `File` the browser tends to download the file, but with `FileContentResult` it displays the image in the browser tab directly, which is the same behavior as using static files. This is probably happening because of the Response Headers being added when using `File`/`FileContentResult` (probably a [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header). Not sure how TopDesk is using these images though.

Off-topic: It's also a good practice to not instantiate a `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider` with every request. Instead, you can register it as a singleton in your Startup.cs like:

```
services.AddSingleton(new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider());
```

and inject it in your controller's constructor.

Comment: Great answer. Changing File to FileContentResult worked like a charm. Also, I was planning on changing the FileExtensionContentTypeProvider for the reason you're giving. I knew i wasn't the best way but still had to change it. First things first ;-)

Comment: @kenhas glad that it helped :)